# Export and use S3 method for 'svd'?

Tags: r

I am trying to create an S3 method for the `svd` function applied to a few custom classes.  To make things as reproducible as possible I have the following trivial example to demonstrate the problem.

Using `roxygen2`:

```
# create generic
svd <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("svd")

# add defai;t
svd.default <- base::svd

#' @export
svd.foo <- function(x, ...){
  print("called svd.foo")
  return(NULL)
}
```

I then build and reload the package.  I can see in the `NAMESPACE`:

```
S3method(svd,foo)
```

However, when I try the call I get the following instead of the message:

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4)
class(mat) <- "foo"
svd(mat)
$d
[1] 2.5909540 2.2850508 1.2608444 0.1467173

$u
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,] -0.1212454  0.3981507 -0.1101441  0.90257625
[2,]  0.4356515  0.4471180 -0.7466406 -0.22982835
[3,]  0.4227691 -0.7681500 -0.3229738  0.35622984
[4,] -0.7853493 -0.2269518 -0.5710376 -0.07506889

$v
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  0.2204894 -0.6736805 -0.2459399  0.66109954
[2,]  0.7409901  0.3288187 -0.5720323 -0.12486370
[3,]  0.0478777 -0.6541094 -0.1526053 -0.73929712
[4,] -0.6324760  0.1008651 -0.7674661  0.02821745
```

It still calls the base `svd` method.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `svd` is not an S3method. If you look at the source code there is no `UseMethod` so it just runs regular `svd` whenever it is called.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that then?  Otherwise I suppose I can just create a new generic for an S4 method.

Comment: @cdeterman Sure, you can just make `svd` into an S3 generic by providing a `svd = function (x, ...) UseMethod('svd')` and in addition `svd.default = base::svd`. No need to go to S4.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, that does it.  I just need to export the generic then.  Thanks, please feel free to put as an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override non-generic functions by generics, and then provide the required method. So in your case:

```
#' @export svd
svd = function (x, ...)
    UseMethod('svd')

#' @S3method svd default
svd.default = base::svd
```

Of course you’d then also add your own method:

```
#' @S3method svd foo
svd.foo <- function(x, ...) {
  print("called svd.foo")
  return(NULL)
}
```

As per Hadley, you should *not* generally `@export` S3 methods — it’s enough to export the generic, and to mark the methods as `@S3method`s.